# Is it possible to block internet access in WebView2?

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I'm using the Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.WebView2 control in a c#/WPF application to display local help html pages. I'd like to turn off or block WebView2's ability to access non-local internet webpages. Is that possible?

Comment: Handle the [`NavigationStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms#step-10---navigation-events) to cancel the non-locals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is subscribe to `WebView2`'s `NavigationStarting` and cancel it if the URI isn't pointing to one of your local files.

```cs
private void webView_NavigationStarting(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    //when navigation to local resources - do nothing
    if (IsUriLocal(e.Uri))
    {
        return;
    }

    //when navigation to any other URI - cancel navigation
    e.Cancel = true;
}

private bool IsUriLocal(string uri)
{
    //check if a URI is local or not
    return uri.StartsWith("https://localhost");
}
```